# pagination missing in Magento catalogue page

Tags: magento

for some reason, the pagination on my Magento catalogue page is missing now. any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

tried [this](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/199172/). and it works now

in catalogue.xml (layout folder under app) had to add

```
<block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
```

in both 'Category layered navigation layout' and 'Category default layout' just under the line

```
<block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
```