# Lost Pagination Toolbar in Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Hello

I have a live Magento 1.8.1 site where pagination was working on product list pages (such as category pages) but I’ve been adding and removing a number of extensions / plugins and I’ve lost all pagination. Unfortunately, I can’t remember the last time it was working so I can’t think precisely what extension might have caused the problem.

I’ve checked all the usual fixes [such as here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350668/pagination-missing-in-magento-catalogue-page) but my catalog.xml is fine (and all problems seem to only relate to 1.4 - 1.6). I am reluctant to upload new files which I actually think might fix it but I also know how temperamental Magento is! Everything else is working perfectly for the first time after a month of serious hard work including a couple of reinstalls!

The website is [next2new.net](http://next2new.net) and although you can see a custom theme, there is also no pagination on the default magento theme which indicates to me it’s a core problem somewhere.

Any thoughts on any files I could check / change before I do a big overwrite?

Many thanks

Comment: Is there any module related with Catalog ? You can disable it and check once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following things you can try in order to Cope-up with this situation :

1) Disable those modules which is overriding Catalog module and check once again.

2) Check whether Toolbar block is calling or not using Template and Block Path hints using Magento Admin.

3) If you are using any template, possibly there could be a setting in Admin section to Manage toolbar.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I waited a little because 1.9 was just released so I thought I would upgrade first to see but it didn't change anything. Anyway, I followed step 1 (not something I've seen before as quite new to Magento) and very early on with disabling, everything is working. Just one plugin was causing the issue so disable and good to go. Thanks so much for your help ... that turned out to be much easier than I thought!